# Select most recent change in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table which consist of four columns:

`TimeStamp | Leg1 | Leg2 | Leg3`

I need to select the leg which was most recently changed as the final leg.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set and expected result please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that only one leg value will change for each time stamp, this will give you the time of last change, what leg was changed, what the new value is and what the previous value was.

Here is a link to see it in action http://rextester.com/ZZHB91131

The code is here:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#thisTest') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #thisTest

CREATE TABLE #thisTest(
DateTimeStamp datetime,
Leg1 int,
Leg2 int,
Leg3 int)

INSERT INTO #thisTest (DateTimeStamp,Leg1,Leg2,Leg3) VALUES
('7/1/2016',1,1,1),
('7/2/2016',2,1,1),
('7/3/2016',2,2,1),
('7/4/2016',2,2,2),
('7/5/2016',2,2,3),
('7/6/2016',2,3,3),
('7/7/2016',3,3,3),
('7/8/2016',3,4,4),
('7/9/2016',4,3,4),
('7/10/2016',4,3,5),
('7/11/2016',4,4,5)

SELECT * FROM #thisTest

SELECT TOP 1
    DateTimeStamp as TimeOfLastChange,
    CASE 
        WHEN LEAD(Leg1) OVER(ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC) <> Leg1 THEN 'Leg1'
        WHEN LEAD(Leg2) OVER(ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC) <> Leg2 THEN 'Leg2'
        WHEN LEAD(Leg3) OVER(ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC) <> Leg3 THEN 'Leg3'
    END AS LegThatWasLastChanged,
    CASE 
        WHEN LEAD(Leg1) OVER(ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC) <> Leg1 THEN LEAD(Leg1) OVER(ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC)
        WHEN LEAD(Leg2) OVER(ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC) <> Leg2 THEN LEAD(Leg2) OVER(ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC)
        WHEN LEAD(Leg3) OVER(ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC) <> Leg3 THEN LEAD(Leg3) OVER(ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC)
    END AS PreviousLegValue,
    CASE 
        WHEN LEAD(Leg1) OVER(ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC) <> Leg1 THEN Leg1
        WHEN LEAD(Leg2) OVER(ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC) <> Leg2 THEN Leg2
        WHEN LEAD(Leg3) OVER(ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC) <> Leg3 THEN Leg3
    END AS LastLegValue
FROM
    #thisTest
ORDER BY
    DateTimeStamp DESC
```

Comment: Additional information let us assume the timeSamp 7/20/2016 Column leg1=9, TimeStamp 7/18/2016 column leg2 =8.5, timeStamp 7/17/2016 column leg3=10.3  ---- ok I want to pic the most recent date for one column leg and consider it as the finalleg.

Comment: @AzizAltamimi was this not what you needed? If not can you elaborate on your question

Comment: Than you for your response. i need the last leg value changed. I knew might be not clear with my first question.

Comment: Im thinking in UNION

Comment: You want only leg3 or which ever leg was changed last?

Comment: Exactly, you are right, I want whatever leg changed last.

Comment: I use CASE statement, but I did not stated right, do you thing in CASE

Comment: Excellent , it working, just I replace the LEAD by RANK because the SQL didnt recognize the LEAD as built in function. Thanks so much.

Comment: No worries @AzizAltamimi  Be sure to accept this answer and / or upvote them and others in the future if they were helpful. I forgot that you were on 2008. LEAD works with 2012 and later versions.